# relationship between virtual memory and core dump

Tags: c++, memory, coredump, virtual-address-space

I have an executable file, and a gcore.

I created core dump file with gcore.

Now, I would like to map the virtual address of the executable file to the core dump.

I know that the core dump is a memory dump of an executable file, and if I would like to analyze virtual address from the core dump. Can I assume that the virtual address `0x0000` equals to offset `0x0000` of the core dump?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that the core dump is a memory dump of an executable file,

No. A core dump in gdb (gcore indicates you're using this) is usually in ELF format, so there's an extensive header definining what maps to what.

I'm not quite sure how much use GDB/linux makes of address space mangling when dumping cores, but you cannot assume file offset x will map to memory offset x -- because the virtual address space can span a **huge** address space, of which it only uses a few pages. (eg. a 64bit process can have a virtual address space that's much much bigger than your hard drive, whilst it might only have actually reserved memory that's far smaller, and even of that, not all pages need actually be allocated).

However, GDB can read these headers and if you ask it to print things (e.g. using the `print` or `x` command), it will give you the right thing.

If you want to read a core dump file, the right thing to do hence is to use GDB's capabilities to do so. Luckily, there's [**libgdb**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/papers/libgdb/libgdb.html), which does exactly that for your C/C++ application. It basically let's you talk with GDB as if you were a user sitting in front of the gdb shell. Hence, figure out how to do what you want in GDB, and then use libgdb to do it programmatically.

If you want to do it lowlevel (don't do that, it's a hassle, and GDB is really what you want to use, actually) you can directly use the [**Binary File Descriptor Library**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library) to parse and represent the core dump. It's an essential part of GDB, and it'll be hard to get it to run with your own C++ program without re-implementing a lot of GDB routines.

Comment: Do you know any way to read virtual address data in core dump from C++?

Comment: @JohnDoyle: see the amendment to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! you are a hero! :)

Comment: Where do I get libgdb.a or so file? It would be wonderful if you have more example on how to use libgdb

Comment: @JohnDoyle: You normally don't really worry about stuff like that, because the build system will take care of detecting things like libgdb's development headers and linker options. So, set up a build system, and install the development package for libgdb, however that is called on your linux distro, or whatever you are using.

Comment: @JohnDoyle, sorry, that is a completely different question. It seems you still need to learn about C/C++ programming. By the way, this is C, not C++, judging by the includes. I think my "job" here is done. You will need to figure the basics of using libraries out yourself, or at least not in the comments to a solution to another question.